# A simple communicate c/s app using QtUdpSocket

Tags: c++, qt

I am a beginner of Qt.I want to use QUdpSocket to write a server app without a GUI.I have writen the client GUI app and server GUI app.They work well.But the server without GUI doesn't work well.

I try to use a while(true) loop to make the app running ,because I think after the code 'return a.exec()' the app will stop.But my server app does't work.

Here is my code:
client with GUI:

```cpp
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    socket=new QUdpSocket(this);
    //click pushbutton send message to server
    connect(this->ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(send()));
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
//send message
void Widget::send()
{
    QByteArray msg="client2:hello world"; 
    socket->writeDatagram(msg.data(),msg.size(),QHostAddress::LocalHost,6666);
}
```

The client app and server with GUI app can work well.But When I try to make a server app without GUI,I found server can not get the message from client.
And here is my server.cpp without GUI:

```cpp
#include "server.h"

Server::Server(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    socket=new QUdpSocket(this);
    array=new QByteArray();
    socket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost,6666,QAbstractSocket::DontShareAddress);
    socket->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite); //without this line, the app will show:
//'QIOBevice::read(QUdpSocket):device not open',but it still can get the message from client.
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(printMsg()));
}

void Server::printMsg()
{
    if(socket->hasPendingDatagrams()) //I forgot this line before.
    {
        array->resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
        socket->readDatagram(array->data(),array->size());
        socket->readAll();
        qDebug()<<"yesyesyes";
    }
}
```

I try many times,I think the problem is in my main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "server.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Server s;

    return a.exec();//after a.exec(),the app is still working!!!
}
```

In a GUI app, if I don't close the windows, the server app will always run, and the SIGNAL and SLOT I can understand.But in a console app, it seems that the app end fast and can't get the message from client(can't display the message).

Comment: Don't post code as images. You should post your code as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), also narrow it to a [mcve] that reproduces your problem please.

Comment: Thanks.I find the mistake when I edit the problem.I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have a `while(true)` in your main, otherwise, you are effectively just freezing your thread and Qt application. This is exactly what `app.exec();` is for, it will return when your application is closed (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770017/qt-what-is-qapplication-simply/55229730#55229730))

If your application (with or without GUI) closes after calling `app.exec()`, it is due to one of the following:

- You are closing it manually, e.g. with `qApp->quit();`
- You are forcing an exit, e.g. with `exit(1);`
- A fatal error or exception prematurely ends your application

Comment: Thanks a lot.Now I understand the app.exec(). After the app.exec(), the app doesn't stop, the signal and slots are still working.I solve my problem. By the way, can you tell me how to make 'app.exec()' obvious like you? Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure! What do you mean by "can you tell me how to make 'app.exec()' obvious like you?"

Comment: The background color of your 'app.exec()' is like gray. It is obvious that it's code.

Comment: Oh sure, you just enclose your `code` with backticks, i.e. that character: `